# correct searching data

Tags: php, sql

i have write a code for search the table data . i provide the multiple column for search . but when i search only single column that time  result is not correct .
Screen Shot :

[image]

query is :--

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    file 
WHERE
    letter = "daak" 
    OR department = "" 
    OR officer = ""
    OR DATE BETWEEN "" AND "" 
ORDER BY
    DATE
```

when i search daak but its show all letter

```
{
 $condition = 'letter ="'.$letter.'" or department = "'.$dept.'" or officer = "'.$officer.'"or date between "'.$fdate.'" and "'.$todate.'" order by date';
          $result =$qgen->select('file','*',$condition);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or result itself is not correct? If result is not correct, did you check the dates, if in case there is not data for selected dates.

Comment: You should check and validate each variable and only add a condition when a variable has a valid value. And use a prepared statement.

Comment: echo variable $condition to make sure your query is displaying right value

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use **STR_TO_DATE** mysql builtin function in your query:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    file 
WHERE
    letter = 'daak'
    OR department = '' 
    OR officer = ''
    OR DATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('10/09/2018','%d/%m/%Y')AND STR_TO_DATE('12/09/2018','%d/%m/%Y') 
ORDER BY
    DATE
```

in your php code:

```
$condition = 'letter ="'.$letter.'" or department = "'.$dept.'" or officer = "'.$officer.'"or date between "STR_TO_DATE('.$fdate.', '%d/%m/%Y')" and "STR_TO_DATE('.$todate.', '%d/%m/%Y')" order by date';
          $result =$qgen->select('file','*',$condition);
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get ONLY rows, where ALL the conditions are met, then use 'and', not 'or'

- 'A and B' means 'only rows where A and also B. not any else row'
- 'A or B' means 'all rows where B and also all rows where A'

so your query should be

```
select * from file where letter ="daak" AND department = "" AND officer
= "" AND date between "" and "" order by date
```

and if you want to ignore empty input fields, then something like

```
{

 $condArray = array();

 if(trim($letter)) $condArray[] = 'letter = "'.$letter.'"';
 if(trim($dept)) $condArray[] = 'department = "'.$dept.'"';
 if(trim($officer)) $condArray[] = 'officer = "'.$officer.'"'
 if(trim($fdate) or trim($todate)) $condArray[] = 'date between "'.$fdate.'" and "'.$todate.'"';

 $condition = implode(' AND ', $condArray).' order by date';

 $result =$qgen->select('file','*',$condition);
}
```